# Unused object while using os.walk

Tags: python, python-3.3

I have the code below to list all the files in directory and subdirectory.

```
def GetListFiles(rootdir,fileextension):
    import os
    testfiles = []
    for root,subfolders,files in os.walk(rootdir):
        for file in files:
            ext = "." + fileextension
            if (os.path.splitext(file)[-1].lower()==ext) and (file!="AssemblyInfo.cs"):
                testfiles.append(os.path.join(root,file))
    return testfiles
```

In the line `for root,subfolders,files in os.walk(rootdir):`, the variable, `subfolders`is not used. If I remove it, it is error

> "too many values to unpack (expected 2)"

How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you want to use a temporary variable, which is not used anywhere, the convention is to use `_`.

```
for root, _, files in os.walk(rootdir):
```

**Note:** Unless you use this is REPL, you can use `_`. In REPL, `_` holds the result of the last evaluated expression.